# best way to order joined select

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, join

I have a main table with which I join several tables using foreign keys (these usually just consist of key + string). I sort them by timestamp (located in the main table) and query the first n entries.
Currently I do all this in one select command.
Is it more efficient to first do a select command with `order by` and `top (n)` and then to join them?
**So I do it now with two selects**

```
SELECT t0.keycol, t0.timestamp, t0.id_1, t0.id_2,
    t1.keycol, t1.timestamp, t1.id_3, t2.id_3,
    t2.value_1, t3.id_1, t3.value_1, t4.id_2,
    t4.value_2, t5.keycol, t5.timestamp, t5.id_1, t5.id_2
FROM (
SELECT t.keycol, t.timestamp, t.id_1, t.id_2
    FROM tbl_1 AS t
    ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
) AS t0
    INNER JOIN tbl_2 AS t1 ON t0.keycol = t1.keycol
    INNER JOIN tbl_3 AS t2 ON t1.Id_3 = t2.id_3
    INNER JOIN tbl_4 AS t3 ON t0.id_1 = t3.id_1
    INNER JOIN tbl_5 AS t4 ON t0.id_2 = t4.id_2
    LEFT JOIN tbl_6 AS t5 ON t1.keycol = t5.keycol

ORDER BY t0.timestamp DESC, t0.keycol, t1.keycol,
 t2.id_3, t3.id_1, t4.id_2, t5.keycol, t5.timestamp
```

Comment: Trust the optimizer, do it all at once.

Comment: can you post some query/code for reference? it would be helpful.

Comment: Sometimes materialising part of a query first can improve performance, especially with large or complex data... have you tested it? You can use SET IO STATISTICS ON to assess what reads it's doing in each case. And/ or run both versions repeatedly and see which is better. If no difference, stick with the simpler single statement.

Comment: Don't try to fix a problem you do not have.

Comment: Optimizer is not always right, that is true. But you should consider optimization in very rear cases. In your situation, I would suggest to to try to move sampling into subquery, if optimizer still insists to join first, you can enforce it by Group By in subquery.